# Counterintuitive design of addition/subtraction between numbers and nullable numbers

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Let's see the following code:

```
int a = 1;
int? b = null;
var addition = a + b;
var subtraction = a - b;
```

I expect both `addition` and `subtraction` is `1`. But in fact both of the two are `null`. The generated code without syntax sugars is like this:

```
int? addition = b.HasValue ? new int?(a + b.GetValueOrDefault()) : new int?();
```

From the view of VB.NET this is more counterintuitive: thre result of `1 + Nothing` is `Nothing`.

I think they could do the addition in this way easily:

```
int addition = a + b.GetValueOrDefault();
//or int? addition = a + b.GetValueOrDefault();
```

But to be honest, the current design doesn't break [its associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). My question is: why do they design the operator like this? What is the disadvantage of my expected behavior?

**EDIT** A few comments mentioned that "because `null` is not `0`", this is absolutely correct. But it's not the reason that `1+null==null`, I didn't say `null` is `0`. Why can't `1+null==1`? Note that: even `1+null==1` and `1+0==1`, we can't infer `null==0`. If so, `1+null==null` and `2+null==null`, I can also infer `1==2`, which makes no sense. Operation rules on `null` is defined by the compiler team, why do they choose this rule, different between adding null to int and string.

**EDIT** consider `null` as "i have no idea", then how did you explain that adding `null` to a string "1" gives the original "1" instead of `null`(i have no idea)? Remember `null` is not `string.Empty`!

**EDIT** I do believe there is no mathematics concerns here, because in some languages `1 + null` returns `1` (try javascript). So it's just a (maybe personal) choice, by the language designer(s). IMO `1 + null == 1` is easier to use than the current design. It's probably a primary-opinion based question.

Comment: Because `null` is *not* `0`.

Comment: Search for "Maybe monad"  - that would reflect another *opinion* on the problem. Null propagation behavior is easier to explain and aligns with NaN behavior for float numbers pretty well - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.nan.aspx

Comment: @Rob But this is not the reason of "1 + null == null"

Comment: Think of null as "I have no idea." Now answer the question "what is 1 plus I have no idea." The answer is probably "I have no idea."

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: "I have no idea" is not precise, here think of `int?` as "it's a int or nothing", now the question is "what is 1 plus a thing that probably is a number, or nothing". The most direct idea is: well, when it's a number ,just add it. when it's nothing, add nothing to it (unmodified). Isn't it?

Comment: That's not what null represents. A null int is not just another value for 0. However, my comment isn't original. See Eric Lippert's blog entry [Null Is Not Empty](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty/) for more.

Comment: Your latest addition to the question is the question "Why can't 1 + null == 1." Let's rephrase that. "Why can't a value I do know plus a value I do not know equal the first value that I do know?" Do you see how nonsensical that question is?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram `why can't 1+null==1` is what I want to ask at the very beginning, sorry for the bad expression. But as you can see in my second edit about `string`, "a string value I do know plus a value I do not know, equals the first value that I do know". The behavior is quite different.

Comment: I can't help you on strings! I can only say that string concatenation was part of the original language design, whereas nullable value types were included in 2.0. The designers of 2.0 clearly had different ideas of what to do than the designers of 1.0 (even if those designers were the same people).

Comment: @DannyChen Because `"1" + null` is a concatenation, not a mathematical operation. Operations on an undefined value *is* very much part of mathematics. Whether or not other languages silently give you a value is irrelevant and almost explicitly the *wrong* way to do it. The only logical (and I mean that in the truest sense of the word) answer is `NaN` (in this case `null`) or an `Exception` is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `1 + null == 1`, then consider the following:

```
int a = 1;
int? b = null;
int result = a + b;
int difference = (a + b) - a;

bool zeroEqualsNull = (difference == b);
```

`result` would be an `int`, not an `int?` as we know `int + null == int`

Clearly, `difference` can be re-arranged to simply `b`. We're then comparing `b == b`, which *should* give `true`.

Yet `b` is `null`, not `0`. And if `0 == null` we'd in a terrible situation. Why even use `int?` at all in that case?

Unless, of course, `difference` turned out to be `int?` - which means either the addition or subtraction operation must, in some cases, return `null`.

P.S. Pointing to javascript as a reference for how a language should behave is a bad idea ;)

Comment: The bug is: `result` and `difference` is of type `int?`. And meanwhile `(a+b)-a` will be `0+b`, this is a `int+int?` expression, if the compiler team use my expected design, `a int plus a null int? equals to the original int`, `0+b==0` succeeds. So as I said, there is no mathematics issue here.

Comment: And by the way, `0+b` is a `int?` type, so you can't ignore the `0+` part and say `b==0`, because this rule applies to int calculations only.

Comment: @DannyChen Why would `result` and `difference` be `int?`. If `1 + null = 1`, and it's a *defined* result, then there is no reason that `int + int? = int?`. That was one of my main points, actually. I wasn't comparing `0+b==0`, it's comparing `0==b`

Comment: Further, why would `(a+b)-a` be `0+b`? It could just as easily be `(a+b==a)-a`, or, `a-a` (since `a+b==a` as per your expectations). And since we know `int + null` always returns the `int`, `a+b-a` would be an `int` equal to `0`.

Comment: You only proved that "in the calculations, `b` has the same effect as `0`", right? Just like `"1"+null == "1"+string.Empty` doesn't mean `null==string.Empty`, it means `null` and `string.Empty` has the same effect in this calculation.

Comment: We have `int a, int? b, int c` and `a+b==a+c` doesn't mean `b==c`.

Comment: @DannyChen No, I showed behaviour smells suspiciously like how an undefined value behaves in mathematics. And as I mentioned before, `"1"+string.Empty` has *nothing* to do with `1+null`. The `+` is not mathematical in any sense, it's simply syntactic sugar to concatenate a result. For the same reason you can't write `"1" - 1`, the difference between strings and integers is large.

Comment: @DannyChen Actually, in mathematics `a+b==a+c` ***most definitely*** means that `b==c`. There is no way `b!=c` unless one of them is an undefined value. And when you do *any mathematical operation* on an undefined value, the result is undefined.

Comment: But it's now not mathematics! We are discussing an operator's behavior when adding an int and a null value (which probably has no corresponding things in mathematics). This operator's rule can be *defined*, unlike the add operator in mathematics.

Comment: @DannyChen Well, you asked for the reason that `C#` returns `null`. I am giving you a reason, I'm not sure what else you're looking for (short of petitioning the C# team to change the language). Programming languages are *inherently* based upon mathematics. Why not define `1+1==3`? We can define it however we want, right? That doesn't mean that it's logical or correct. If you want to do mathematical operations (and as much as you argue against it, it *is* a mathematical operation), you better be sure to make it *correct*, or you're in for a hell of a time.

Comment: @DannyChen Except it _is_mathematics. Using `null` in code is much like using "undefined" in a mathematics operation, and in math performing an operation on anything involving "undefined" can't result in anything other than "undefined". Would you define `1 / 0 = 0`? Because that's essentially what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @DannyChen If it really grinds your gears so much, then you can overload the `int?` arithmetic operators to implement the behavior you want to use. But I have to point out that doing so eliminates a lot of the purpose behind using a nullable type in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your logic is that `null` is not the same thing as `0`. `0` is a value, whereas null by definition means a lack of a value. How do you add together a value and a lack of a value?

Think of it like this. I have one marble in one hand and no marbles in my other hand. I can then say that I have `1 + 0` marbles, or one marble.

Then say I had one marble in one hand and in the other hand I had a box with an unknowable number of marbles in it. I would have `1 + ?` marbles. So how many marbles do I have?

Trying to add a value and `null` together is trying to apply arithmetic to two completely different concepts. There is no objective way to say what kind of value would come out of the operation, so the most straightforward way to deal with it is to say that there is no value, a.k.a `null`.

**EDIT:** In response to your point about strings, the reason strings act differently is because strings themselves are completely different from integers. `1 + null` makes no sense, but `"1" + null` is the same as saying you are combining an array with an empty array, so it makes sense that you end up with the same array that you started with.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they designed it this way because it makes the most sense.

First you need to know that `null` isn't the same as `0`. `null` means *literally* NOTHING. There is absolutely nothing there! `0` on the other hand, is SOMETHING. It has a value, and that value is `0`!

We all know that 1 + 0 = 1, but what is 1 + nothing? You can see the operation like this:

```
1 +
```

There is nothing on the other side of the `+`! And the computer can't do addition with only one operand! So it returns null.

Comment: I think what makes the most sense is: when I add nothing to 1, nothing is added to 1, so I get the original thing, that is 1.

Comment: @DannyChen You aren't understanding. There is a difference between 0 and nothing. Saying "1 + null" is not the same conceptually as saying "adding nothing to 1". You might as well be trying to do "1 + red".

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to argue and counter argue that

> 1 + 0 = 1 + nothing = 1

But our analysis is heuristic. We are taking contextual meaning also. For a computer which by the way is running on only 0 and 1 (binary i.e.) has been designed to treat 0 as integer that has a value. 
On the other hand NULL can be used for anything that has no value. so its used in string, int, float, char everywhere but represents the variable not to have any value.

There was no need to have it complicated by adding scenarios that rarely happens.

Now the way addition is seen in our systems are addition of 2 values.
The place where we have nothing or Null is not coded in to return and other value. 
But if you override the + operator to take into consideration nothing (null) you can achieve what your are looking for.

Hope this explains your question.