# C# Determine difference between DateTime and DateTime? (Nullable)

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to determine the difference between a DateTime and a DateTime? using reflection.  Please see my test code below:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public DateTime testDate1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? testDate2 { get; set; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        TestClass testing = new TestClass();
        var props = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
        {
            object o = p.GetValue(testing);
            if (typeof(DateTime?).IsInstanceOfType(o))
            {
                o = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (typeof(DateTime).IsInstanceOfType(o))
            {
                if (((DateTime)o) == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    o = null;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", p.Name, (o ?? "NULL").ToString()));
        }

    }
```

The output of this code is the opposite to what i would expect.  Currently the output is:

testDate1 = 26/01/2016 16:15:00

testDate2 = NULL

I am expecting testDate1 to be null and testDate2 to contain the value.

When debugging this code, it seems that the first pass using testDate1 passes both of the typeof if statements, the second fails both of the if statements.  Can anybody help me understand and hopefully try and catch the specific nullable instance of the date time?

To note i have also tried switching to a definition and test on Nullable just in case, but it made no difference.

Many thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to have a boxed nullable type. Either the object is a DateTime or it is a null reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here... `DateTime` is a struct, it can't have a null value. That's why you explicitly need to use the `?` notation to allow it be null.

Comment: You might be interested to look at this recent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938774/counterintuitive-design-of-addition-subtraction-between-numbers-and-nullable-num/34942047#34942047

Comment: Thanks. @MageXy I am trying to determine the difference between DateTime and DateTime? because they need to be handled differently. ChrisF I was trying to demonstrate that a DateTime type satisfies both of the tests on the typeof statements.  Ian thanks, i understand there is a compelling argument to not use nullable types but the system i am working on has a mixture of some places use it and some places don't - and they are expected to behave differently through common logic!  Surely there is a way?

Comment: If you need these two properties to be handled differently then you need to check the PropertyInfo's PropertyType. The value that is retrieved is not able to tell you whether the property was nullable or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, keep in mind that `testDate1` can never be null because `DateTime` is a **struct**. If you declare a `DateTime` without intitializing it, it will get the default value of `DateTime.MinValue`. `testDate2`, on the other hand, is a Nullable struct, where the default value is null(-ish... it's actually a value that represents null, but not null itself).

IsInstanceOfType is using `o`'s `GetType()` method in the background to verify that its type is the same as the type you are comparing to (in this case, `DateTime?`). However, if you take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789(v=VS.90).aspx), it states:

> Calling GetType on a Nullable type causes a boxing operation to be performed when the type is implicitly converted to Object. Therefore GetType always returns a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type.

So, if you step through the foreach loop for the `testDate1` property, you'll see that the first condition will return true (since `testDate1` can't be null, which means it *has to* be of type `DateTime`). You then step into the second if-condition (though that's effectively just doing the same check again), but you don't enter the inner if because `o` currently has a value of `DateTime.Now`.

Now stepping through for `testDate2` (which is holds a null value), you will see that you don't enter *either* of the if-conditionals because null doesn't have a type. As such, your object will remain null throughout the second iteration of the loop, giving you the output you see there.

---

NOTE: Just so you know, the way you're "assigning" values to `o` doesn't modify the original TestClass at all. Consider the following:

```
TestClass testing = new TestClass();
var prop = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("testDate1");

// Here we get the current value of testing.testDate1, which is the default DateTime.MinValue
object o = prop.GetValue(testing);

// Here we set o to null... has ZERO effect on testing.testDate1. 
o = null;

// What you actually want is probably the following.
// (Remember though that testDate1 can't be null... this just sets it back to DateTime.MinValue.)
prop.SetValue(testing, null);
```

Comment: `testDate2, on the other hand, is a nullable object, so its default value is null.`  It's a `Nullable<DateTime>`, and `Nullable` is a `struct`, so its default value is *not* `null`  It's the default value of the `Nullable` struct, which happens to *conceptually represent* `null`, even though *it's not null*.

Comment: Good point, I've updated my answer to reflect that. Would you agree that conceptually you can treat a Nullable<T> as an object in most situations?

Comment: No, you cannot.  And it's *certainly* wrong to treat it as such in this example, as this example is showing that `Nullable` not only doesn't act like a user defined class, it doesn't even act like a normal struct.  There is special compiler behavior *specifically for the nullable type* affecting the behavior of the program in question, so **you can't treat it as anything except exactly what it is**.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can't.

If you have an `object date` there is no way to know if it orginally comes from a nullabe `DateTime` or not.

```
DateTime? nullable = DateTime.Now;
object o = nullable;
```

The assignment to `o` is morally equivalent to

```
object temp = null;

if (nullable.HasValue)
{
    temp = nullable.Value;
}

o = temp;
```

As you can see, the information of the nullable type is lost and what you are really getting is the boxed nullable's value.

This is easy to see by simply doing `o.GetType()` which will return `DateTime` if the nullable had a value or you will get a `NullReferenceException` if it didn't.

This does not mean that you can not determine if the declared type of a property, method or member is nullable or not. You can do this easily enough via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for so much useful comments and links.  I realise that it was the property i should have been inspecting and not the object.  I am using this:

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType)
```

It allows me to determine what i am dealing with and is pretty effective.  I still end up switching on typeof(T).Name but i will cross that bridge when i come to it :)

I have to live with the fact that functional code vs ugly code remains an internal battle!